# Arr.push inside For-loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a SPA built with Vue and I'm trying to fetch an array of items from a custom API.

Once I've stored the items I'm trying to loop through that array and push in a custom path value, however I get the error

> this.list[i].push is not a function

I'm not sure why this wouldn't be possible, but I'm sure I've missed something.

```
this.list: []

fetch(){
   let url =  'http://core.com/api/v0/sources/'

   axios.get(url).then((response) => {
       this.list = response.data.data

       for(var i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++){
           let arr = { path: '/testPath' }
           this.list[i].push(arr)
       }
   })
}
```

Comment: How is `this.list` initialized?

Comment: You seem to be trying to build an array of arrays of a single object - is that really the best data structure for your needs?

Comment: You say it's an array of items; if by "items" you mean "objects", you need `this.list[i].path = '/testPath';` (the error is telling you that a single array element is not also an array)

Comment: `this.list[i]` is not an array. please `console.log(this.list[i])` so we can help.

Comment: @ChrisG ```this.list[i].path``` does not exist, that is what Im trying to create

Comment: I think you would put something like this `this.list.push(arr)` not `this.list[i].push(arr)`

Comment: "this.list[i].path does not exist, that is what Im trying to create"...if you literally want to add a property called "path" directly under the object at `this.list[i]` then you'd write `this.list[i].path = '/testPath'`

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi that would overwrite the contents of the list which was downloaded from the server

Comment: @ADyson Yeah sure but I'm bit confused what this guy to achieve here

Comment: @ADyson This solved the problem. Thank you for helping me think, I was clearly on the wrong trajectory.

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi I think OP has made it pretty clear by saying `this.list[i].path does not exist, that is what Im trying to create`. But for definite, I don't think they can be wanting to download some data and then immediately overwrite it with something else. I can't think a reason anyone would want to achieve that. So that's why I commented on your suggestion, because it doesn't make much sense in any scenario,

Comment: @josjo No problem. ChrisG did actually say the same thing in the 3rd comment.

Comment: @ADyson got you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you mentioned your goal:

> "this.list[i].path does not exist, that is what Im trying to create"

...if you literally want to add a property called "path" directly under the object at this.list[i] then you'd write

```
this.list[i].path = '/testPath'
```

This will create a new property for the object being held at `this.list[i]`.

---

P.S.

You don't need your (badly-named) `arr` variable at all here.

Using `.push()` doesn't make any sense (and doesn't work) because `this.list[i]` contains an object rather than an array, and also doing that wouldn't create a property as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

**push** is the function of an array but you are trying to push an object in an object that's why  you got this exception.

you can do as below.

```
this.list[i].path = '/testPath'
```

**path** property will be dynamically added in your object **this.list[i]**.